# Trouble dumping into HTML string into Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm playing around with a Rails application that intends to display an HTML rendering of some XML data that I have.

I used Nokogiri to transform an XML document to a string of HTML markup in my controller, and then, in the view, I am try to display it. But when I load the page, all of the HTML markup `<div>`, etc., are being treated as part of the string rather than as HTML markup.

The transformation logic looks like this:

```
def xslt_apply_to(xml_open_uri_file, xsltfile, xslt_param_array)
    xml  = xml_open_uri_file
    xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(open(xsltfile))
    result_doc = xslt.apply_to(xml, xslt_param_array)
    return result_doc
end
```

Where `xml_open_uri_file` is the XML file I'm transforming and `xsltfile` is the file I'm using to transform it.

This method returns a String containing

```
"<div><p>Test test test test test</p></div>"
```

captured below in `@transform`:

```
@transform = xslt_apply_to(xmldoc,xsltdoc,xslt_param_array)
```

Then I am trying to include this in my view as follows:

```
<div id="lbp-text-body" class="container">
    <%= @transform %>
<div>
```

But the result appearing in the browser is:

```
<div><p>Test test test test test</p></div>
```

When what I really want is the text wrapped in a `<div>` and `<p>` that the browser recognizes. So all I should see in the browser is:

```
Test test test test test
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: You can use `strip_tags("<div><p>Test test test test test</p></div>")` it should return `Test test test test test`

Comment: oh, let be more clear, I want the html that I'm importing to render as html. I don't want to strip the tags. I want them to be recognized by the browser as html tags

Comment: Have you tried `<%= raw(@transform) %>`

Comment: success with raw!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= raw(@transform) %>
```

`raw()` is a wrapper around `html_safe()` that forces the input to String and then calls `html_safe()` on it.

You can refer to "[SafeBuffers and Rails 3.0](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Another option. Have you tried `html_safe`? It's one less processing step than `raw`, which is like a call `to_s` then `html_safe` appended. A shortcut, but use only if you know your string is non-nil.

```
<%= @transform.html_safe %>
```